# Can't get RelativeLayout to set above another RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendToLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#292929" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sendToType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="To" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/previewlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sendToLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:text="Message Preview: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageLayout" >

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/messagePreview"
        android:text="Message Preview will be shown here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addNumberButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Contacts" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enterMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageLayout3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addNumberButton"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:hint="Message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The highlighted RelativeLayout (**@+id/previewLayout**)

[image]

should only go to the top of *this* RelativeLayout (**@+id/messageLayout**):

[image]

But it goes all the way to the bottom of the screen/parent. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try changing height of first RelativeLayout to a fixed size, and check if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line in your `@+id/previewlayout` Relative layout node..

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/messageLayout"
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sendToLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#292929" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Contacts"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sendToType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="To" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addNumberButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageLayout3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Contacts" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/enterMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/messageLayout3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addNumberButton"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:hint="Message" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/previewlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/messageLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sendToLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:text="Message Preview: "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/previewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageLayout" >

        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/messagePreview"
        android:text="Message Preview will be shown here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```